# Unity2d Newbie Code error ReferenceProblem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance, nullreferenceexception

I simply want to retrieve the value of a string from a different script.
Trying to get the value of selectedElement in script1.

Script1:

```
public class ElementSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dropdown dropdown;
    public string selectedElement;
    public List<string> element = new List<string>();

    void Start()
    {
        dropdown.GetComponent<Dropdown>();
        dropdown.options.Clear();

        element.Add("Top");
        element.Add("Bottom");
        element.Add("Outlines");

        foreach (var item in element)
        {
            dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData() { text = item });
        }

        dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { DropdownElementSelected(dropdown); });  
    }

    public void DropdownElementSelected(Dropdown dropdown)
    {
        CurrentElement();
    }

    public string CurrentElement()
    {
        selectedElement = element[dropdown.value];
        return selectedElement;
    }

}
```

Script2:

```
public class Paint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string element;

    public void SetColor()
    {
        
        element = GetComponent<ElementSelector>().selectedElement;
        Debug.Log("thefuck: " + element);         
        
    }
}
```

I've been struggling to understand for so long and the other day I had a very similar problem but after 9 hours I realized that I needed to drag a thing to a thing in the Unity interface that was the reference problem. However Now I don't think I have a physical game component to reference?

I just want the damn string value..

UPDATE!

Now I got the value from the variable. So I've now got it in a string variable in my Paint class but I got stuck again with reference error further down the line.

So here's a screenshot of my hierarchy
[image]

This is very strange to me even considering you guys have taught me about components and gameobejct cus as I see it, now I have the value in a string in the same damn class I'm trying to push it out from.

In the thing below, if I replace "bottom" with the value of elementSelector which has the value of "bottom" (tested and working) it will give me a reference error.

```
if (create.GraffitiLetters.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < create.GraffitiLetters.Count; i++)
            {
                string elementSelector;
                elementSelector = FindObjectOfType<ElementSelector>().selectedElement;
              
                GameObject barn = create.GraffitiLetters[i].transform.Find("bottom").gameObject;
                barn.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colorPicker.GetColor();
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure both scripts are in same gameobject, because you used GetComponent. Alternetively you can call like this `element = FindObjectOfType<ElementSelector>().selectedElement;`

Comment: omg. The first one you suggested didnt work for me but the second one did provided I attach both script to the same gameobject. It's so weird for me to understand that the scripts need to be on the same object, why? Anyways. Thank you very much Jaimin.

Comment: Jaimin...well I got the value from the variable alright...second after I got a new referenceerror...omg. now I have to understand how to solve that freaking problem. a whole new beast to tackle.

Comment: What's the Error ?? and Please attach that code which gives error

Comment: I posted an answer with the new problem. I don't know how to copy the error from the console but its a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. problem derives from this GameObject barn = create.GraffitiLetters[i].transform.Find(elementSelector).gameObject;
                barn.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colorPicker.GetColor(); where elementSelector is fucked for some reason. replacing it with any string or a new string var value works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity you've got GameObjects and Components. When you create a script you inherit from MonoBehavior. That script then is assigned to a GameObject. This MonoBehavior then is a Component on the GameObject.

So you've got a GameObject, let's call it `MyMenuObject`, and then you assign your `ElementSelector` script to it. `ElementSelector` is now a Component of `MyMenuObject`. Within the SomethingMenu class you can also access the GameObject, e.g. `GameObject thisObject = this.gameObject`.

Now you've got your Paint class, which will also be a Component. Therefore your Paint script needs to be added to a GameObject. Now your Paint class is accessing another Component by `GetComponent`. So you're requesting the ElementSelector Component from the GameObject that has the Paint script assigned.

Therefore you need to make sure that both of your scripts are assigned to one and the same GameObject.

Comment: Thank you AndAs, it's still abstract for me but I now know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you AndAs, it's still abstract for me but I now know what to look for. Is This the same issue with reference problem? I manage to grab the value from my original problem thanx to Jaimim but right after the next reference error.

```
string elementSelector;
elementSelector = FindObjectOfType<ElementSelector>().selectedElement;
```

this works. got it. its now in a string in my Paint class. Now I have this thing that suppose to paint part of my thing.

```
GameObject barn = create.GraffitiLetters[i].transform.Find("bottom").gameObject;
barn.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colorPicker.GetColor();
```

Which works but if I replace "bottom" with the value of elementSelector its a reference error. how can that be. now im in the same damn class and still its calling a reference problem. sorry if im being thick, this is like day 3 in Unity for me.

Comment: It's a bit unclear how your GameObjects look like. Can you post a screenshot of your GameObject Hierachy? transform.Find returns a child gameobject with the given name. I believe your GameObject has a child GameObject named "bottom", but when you're talking about elementSelector you're talking about Components, not GameObjects. So if your "bottom" GameObject has an ```ElementSelector``` component which you'd like to access you would do: ```ElementSelector barnSelector = barn.GetComponent<ElementSelector>()```

Comment: heck yeah man. i've posted an update with screenshot. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

I actually don't know how I did it, I made so many different attempts and it all seem to be the way it was before when I got the error so can't say what it was.